# Stencil buffer clear values not 0?

Tags: opengl-es, webgl

Ive been trying to understand / debug a problem to do with the stencil buffer. I probably dont understand how it works versus how I think it works. Essentially I have a scene where I render all my solid objects and assign them a stencil value of 1. I then go through the same scene again, but the second time I render only the transparent objects and give them a stencil value of 2. In the final step I have a screen quad that draws the scene to a texture. I want to use the stencil buffer to only draw the final quad where the stencil bits were set to 1 or 2. So in code:

```
// First enable the stencil buffer
gl.enable( gl.STENCIL_TEST );
gl.clearStencil( 0 );
gl.clear(gl.STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT); // presumably this clears the buffer to 0?

// ...for the solid meshes
gl.stencilFunc( gl.ALWAYS, 1, 0xffffffff ); // Always pass the stencil
gl.stencilOp( gl.REPLACE, gl.REPLACE, gl.REPLACE ); // Replace the stencil value with ref=1


// ...for the transparent meshes
gl.stencilFunc( gl.ALWAYS, 2, 0xffffffff ); // Always pass the stencil
gl.stencilOp( gl.REPLACE, gl.REPLACE, gl.REPLACE ); // Replace the stencil value with ref=2

// ...for the final screen quad
gl.stencilFunc( gl.GEQUAL, 1, 0xffffffff ); // Only draw the bits higher than 1 (so 1 and 2 should be included)
gl.stencilOp( gl.KEEP, gl.KEEP, gl.KEEP); //  Dont touch the stencil values in the buffer
```

However this never seems to work. From my tests it seems as though the stencil values are set to 0xffffffff before I assign them values. This makes the GEQUAL test pointless as the buffer values are greater than 0.

I created a JS fiddle to demo what I mean. I draw a small square and assign its values to 4. Then draw a bigger square and test for gequal to 5. I would have thought that the bigger square would always fail. However it always passes. When I test using gl.stencilFunc( gl.GEQUAL, 4, 0xffffffff ); I see the correct small square only. But when I test  gl.stencilFunc( gl.GEQUAL, 0xffffff, 0xffffffff ); then it also looks correct. This to me says that the stencil buffer is not set to 0?

http://jsfiddle.net/90af0rov/

Im really confused and would appreciate any pointers on this <:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the GEQUAL operation the wrong way around in stencilFunc.
See the documentation here: https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glStencilFunc.xml

> GL_GEQUAL
>                           Passes if ( ref & mask ) >= ( stencil & mask ).

So in your code example, it will only draw when ref (which is 1) is greater equal to the value currently in the stencil buffer. If you change it to:

```
gl.stencilFunc( gl.LESS, 0, 0xffffffff );
```

Then it should fix it, as it will now pass if the ref of zero is less than the value in the stencil buffer. You could also use NOTEQUAL instead of LESS in this case.